# Proof of equality for Holder's inequality (need verification)

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, holder-inequality

For positive finite sequence $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ and $b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{n}$, the inequality below holds:
$$
a_{1}b_{1} + ... + a_{n} b_{n} \le \left( a_{1}^{p} + ... + a_{n}^{p} \right)^{1/p} \left( b_{1}^{q} + ... + b_{n}^{q} \right)^{1/q}, \:\:\: \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 $$

---

**Proof and attempt:**

Consider the inequality:

$$ x^{\alpha} y^{\beta} \le \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} x^{\alpha + \beta} + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} y^{\alpha + \beta} $$

for all $x > 0, y > 0$, and integers $\alpha > 0$, and $\beta > 0$. This is obtained by using the general AM-GM inequality by considering $\alpha + \beta$ numbers: there are $\alpha$ $x^{\alpha + \beta}$s and $\beta$ $y^{\alpha + \beta}$s. We have by AM-GM:

$$ \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha + \beta} + \beta y^{\alpha + \beta}}{\alpha + \beta} \ge \left( x^{\alpha(\alpha + \beta)} y^{\beta(\alpha + \beta)} \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha + \beta}} $$
$$ \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha + \beta} + \beta y^{\alpha + \beta}}{\alpha + \beta} \ge x^{\alpha} y^{\beta} $$

Now notice that if we set $ p = \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\alpha}, q = \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\beta} $ then $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. The inequality above becomes:

$$ x^{\alpha} y^{\beta} \le \frac{1}{p} x^{\alpha p} + \frac{1}{q} y^{\beta q} $$

Now let $u = x^{\alpha}, v = y^{\beta}$:

$$ u v \le \frac{1}{p} u^{p} + \frac{1}{q} v^{q} $$

Now use this many times: $u = a_{i}, v = b_{i}, \:\: i = 1, ..., n$, and then sum all of the $n$ inequalities to get:

$$ a_{1}b_{1} + ... + a_{n} b_{n} \le \frac{1}{p}  \sum_{i=1}^{n}  a_{i}^{p} + \frac{1}{q} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  b_{i}^{q}  $$

Now we use the fact that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1$, by the transformation $a_{i} = \frac{a_{i}^{*}}{ \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k}^{*})^{p} \right)^{1/p} }$ and $b_{i} = \frac{b_{i}^{*}}{ \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_{k}^{*})^{q} \right)^{1/q} }$.

$$ \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}^{*} b_{k}^{*} }{ \left(  \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k}^{*})^{p} \right)^{1/p}   \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_{k}^{*})^{q} \right)^{1/q}  }   $$
$$ \le   \frac{1}{p}  \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{(a_{i}^{*})^{p}}{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k}^{*})^{p}  }  + \frac{1}{q} \sum_{i=1}^{n}   \frac{ (b_{i}^{*})^{q}}{  \sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_{k}^{*})^{q}  } $$

$$ \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}^{*} b_{k}^{*} }{ \left(  \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k}^{*})^{p} \right)^{1/p}   \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_{k}^{*})^{q} \right)^{1/q}  }   $$
$$ \le   \frac{1}{p}  + \frac{1}{q} = 1  $$

$$   \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}^{*} b_{k}^{*} \le \left(  \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k}^{*})^{p} \right)^{1/p}   \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_{k}^{*})^{q} \right)^{1/q}    $$

Now for the **equality**, here is my attempt..**which is a bit inconsistent with the one from [The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cauchyschwarz-master-class/A444E291C6E5928ADB2DD9F37C4C6EB8) .** Therefore I would like verification whether or not the author meant something different, or maybe typo.

Using our last inequality of our proof, equality is when:

$$   \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}^{*} b_{k}^{*} = \left(  \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k}^{*})^{p} \right)^{1/p}   \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_{k}^{*})^{q} \right)^{1/q}    $$
If we recall the form $a_{k}, b_{k}$ to a form involving $a_{k}^{*}, b_{k}^{*}$, the above is equivalent to

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} b_{k}  =   \frac{1}{p}  \sum_{i=1}^{n}  a_{i}^{p} + \frac{1}{q} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  b_{i}^{q}  $$

which is also equivalent with

$$ a_{k} b_{k}  =  \frac{a_{k}^{p}}{p} + \frac{b_{k}^{q}}{q}, \:\: k=1,2,...,n $$

recall that this is the result from our general AM-GM usage in the proof, when equality happens. That is when $a_{k}^{p} = b_{k}^{q}$. Using our previous transformation again, the equation is equivalent with

$$ \left( \frac{a_{k}^{*}}{ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}^{*})^{p} \right)^{1/p} } \right)^{p} = \left( \frac{b_{k}^{*}}{ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_{i}^{*})^{q} \right)^{1/q} } \right)^{q} $$

$$ \frac{(a_{k}^{*})^{p}}{ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}^{*})^{p} \right) }  = \frac{(b_{k}^{*})^{q}}{ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_{i}^{*})^{q} \right) }  $$

$$ \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_{i}^{*})^{q} \right) (a_{k}^{*})^{p}}{ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}^{*})^{p} \right) }  = (b_{k}^{*})^{q} $$

Write $\lambda =  \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_{i}^{*})^{q} \right)}{ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}^{*})^{p} \right) } $ and we get the equality condition $ \lambda (a_{k}^{*})^{p} = (b_{k}^{*})^{q} $ (this is a bit different with the result from the book)

Comment: Your proof is right, but there is something much more easier. Also, your formulation of Holder (known standard formulation) is not so easy for using. There is more natural formulation. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/holder-inequality/info Actually, the equality in the linked formulation occurs for $\vec{a}||\vec{b}.$